# Is it possible to upgrade Gstreamer and libx264 on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, codecs, gstreamer, h264

Ubuntu 18.04 has 1.14 Gstreamer installed and `libx264-152`. Is it possible to upgrade it to 1.16 or 1.18 as well as some dependent libraries like: `libx264-155` and `libx265`? Whether some PPA exists or need to build from sources?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yet, it is possible. Use the [following PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Esavoury1/+archive/ubuntu/ffmpeg4?field.series_filter=bionic) for both x264/x265 and GStreamer:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:savoury1/ffmpeg4
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:savoury1/multimedia
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Reverting is possible by

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:savoury1/ffmpeg4
sudo ppa-purge ppa:savoury1/multimedia
```

You can always use both [Y PPA Manager](https://launchpad.net/%7Ewebupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/y-ppa-manager) or visit https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas to do a search by yourself.

Comment: Thanks much! Seems what I need, of course I tried to search through launchpad however did not find anything useful: may be wrong link to search from or wrong keyword.

Comment: Also need to add `ppa:savoury1/multimedia` repo otherwise `gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad` is not installed because of missed `libsoundtouch1` package dependency.

Comment: Unfortunately above PPA updates not only GStreamer but many other packages including fontconfig, which makes it unusable in Appimage as need to bundle somehow many other dependencies. Is there any other good PPA? https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas does not allow to filter by Ubuntu versions.Thanks!

Comment: Please install Y PPA Manager on the target system and do a search by yourself. The example for x265 [is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjSAY.png). Other possible way is to Pin packages which you do not want to be upgraded. It is complex procedure, so I can't find time for it. You are welcome to add your findings to answer above by editing it. Bug about PPA version search [is here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/launchpad/+bug/1820387), please mark yourself as affected.

Comment: Of course I tried `Y PPA Manager` - it is terrible, no way to check ubuntu version there, included packages, etc. And all this deb ecosystem is terrible and very complex to use. Ubuntu/debian users need to try openSUSE some day to see there is much more friendly and easy to use distros exists. 2nd thing: I can't pin `fontconfig` as `gstreamer` depends on it - on specific version it was built with. So pinning them has no effect.